# Parallelizing a SLURM job for multiple files

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, slurm, hpc

I want to run the following code using GNU parallel - one *.mcool file at a time.

The following code in `run_eaglec2.sh` runs [predictSV](https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC) on each *.mcool file in the directory.

First attempt:

```
for mcool_file in *.mcool; do

  OUTPUT=$(echo "$mcool_file" | grep -oE "[A-Z0-9]*\.hg38" | cut -d '.' -f 1)

  cooler ls "$mcool_file" | grep -E '\/[1][0]{4}$|\/[5][0]{3,4}$' \
  | tr '\n' '\t' \
  | parallel --colsep '\t' --link -j2000 \
  --eta --progress --bar --joblog $mcool_file'_parallel.log' \
  predictSV --hic-5k {1} --hic-10k {2} --hic-50k {3} \
  -O './../EagleC_output/raw/'$OUTPUT -g hg38 --balance-type raw --output-format full \
  --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999 2> $mcool_file'.stderr'
  # | tr -d "'"

done
```

Second attempt:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo "$1" | grep -oE "[A-Z0-9]*\.hg38" | cut -d '.' -f 1)

cooler ls "$1" | grep -E '\/[1][0]{4}$|\/[5][0]{3,4}$' \
  | tr '\n' '\t' \
  | parallel --colsep '\t' --link -j2000 \
  --eta --progress --bar --joblog $1'_parallel.log' \
  predictSV --hic-5k {1} --hic-10k {2} --hic-50k {3} \
  -O './../EagleC_output/raw/'$OUTPUT -g hg38 --balance-type raw --output-format full \
  --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999 2> $1'.stderr'
  # | tr -d "'"
```

Third attempt:

```
for mcool_file in *.mcool; do
    OUTPUT=$(echo "$mcool_file" | grep -oE "[A-Z0-9]*\.hg38" | cut -d '.' -f 1)

    resolutions=$(cooler ls "$mcool_file" | grep -E '\/[1][0]{4}$|\/[5][0]{3,4}$')

    while IFS=$'\t' read -r res_5k res_10k res_50k; do
        predictSV --hic-5k "$res_5k" --hic-10k "$res_10k" --hic-50k "$res_50k" \
            -O "./../EagleC_output/raw/$OUTPUT" -g hg38 --balance-type raw --output-format full \
            --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999 2> "${mcool_file}.stderr"
    done <<< "$resolutions"
done
```

I tried to run `sbatch run_eaglec2.sh {} ::: *.mcool` to parallelize the job but it is killed without any SLURM output.